# Azure custom resource provider long running resource creation

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I need to create a custom resource provider with an Azure function in the backend. So my ARM template would look something like this - https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-custom-rp-with-function/azuredeploy.json

I am confused about how I must design this Azure function. I want to understand how a resource of custom resource type is provisioned through ARM template.

When the custom resource is provisioned through ARM template, is a POST request made and response of the API would determine if the provisioning succeeded or failed?

If so how can I put a long running operation here? Can my POST call give a response after 1.5 hours of processing?

Or in custom resource provisioning through ARM template, would POST call be made followed by GET calls till the GET call returns 200 OK?

Comment: Built-in RPs return a 202 Accepted I think? Then the status can be polled by Azure. I don't know the specifics of that, but I'd look at how e.g. the virtualMachines RP works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link which answers the question - https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-rpc/blob/master/v1.0/Addendum.md

Comment: 404 - This is not the web page you are looking for